# Jsoup take <tr> tag data

Tags: java, web-crawler, jsoup

I am trying out the following code and i expected the result that menuList has some Nodes.
But menuList doesn't have any Node. Why is that?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String connUrl = "http://www.hstree.org/c03/c03_00.php";
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(connUrl).get();
            Elements elements = doc.select("table");
            for (Element element : elements) {
                // System.out.println(element.attributes());
                if (element != null && (element.id().equals("1gn") || element.id().equals("2gn"))) {
                    Node childNode = element.childNodes().get(0);
                    List<Node> menuList = childNode.childNodes();
                    System.out.println(element.id()+" menu");
                    for(Node menu : menuList) {
                        System.out.println(menu.childNodes().get(0).toString());
                        System.out.println(" : " + menu.childNodes().get(1).toString());
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: I think your question should go to code review.

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`childNodes` returns everything including text. You need to use `children()` and `Element`:

```
String connUrl = "http://www.hstree.org/c03/c03_00.php";
try {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(connUrl).get();
    Elements elements = doc.select("table");
    for (Element element : elements) {
        // System.out.println(element.attributes());
        if (element != null && (element.id().equals("1gn") || element.id().equals("2gn"))) {
            Element childNode = element.child(0);
            List<Element> menuList = childNode.children();
            System.out.println(element.id() + " menu");
            for (Element menu : menuList) {
                System.out.println(menu.child(0));
                System.out.println(" : " + menu.child(1));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```